# Image resize issue in firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, resize

I am trying to resize an image using the following code

This is the image uploader tags

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="imgUpload" onchange="readURLBottom(this)" value="Select" >
<ul id="logoPlaceholder"></ul>
```

And this is the following javascript code that I am using for image resize

```
var objBottom, reader, imgData, maxHeight, maxWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth; 

function readURLBottom(input) 
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
    {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
            objBottom = new Image();
            objBottom.src = e.target.result;

            imageHeight  = objBottom.height;
            imageWidth  = objBottom.width;

            if (imageWidth > maxWidth) 
            {
                imageHeight = imageHeight / (imageWidth / maxWidth);
                imageWidth = maxWidth;
            }

            var c = document.createElement('canvas');

            c.height = imageHeight;
            c.width = imageWidth;

            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(objBottom, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

            objBottom.src = c.toDataURL();

            var strToAppend = '<li class="span3"><a  class="thumbnail"><i onclick=RemoveImage(this) class="icon-remove pull-right"></i><img src="' + objBottom.src + '" width="100px"/></a></li><p></p>';
            $("#logoPlaceholder").html(strToAppend);

        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

This works fine in Chrome. But this does not works on Firefox. I am getting zero for the following two values in Firefox.

```
imageHeight  = objBottom.height;
imageWidth  = objBottom.width;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to fit a large image into a thumbnail drawn over a Canvas. Right?

Comment: Actually I am just trying to upload an image from a open file dialog box. Whether the image is bigger or smaller in pixel, this problem occurs in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try using your code `onload` of the image object.

```
objBottom = new Image();
objBottom.onload = function(){
    //Your code
}
objBottom.src = //set the source here
```

Also check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've passed by the same situation.

You can try this:

```
imageHeight = objBottom.height;
imageWidth  = objBottom.width;    

if ((imageHeight==0)&&(imageWidth==0)){  //Firefox issue
    readURLBottom(input);  //recursive call
}
```

It works for me. I hope it can help you.